# What are the equivalent F# bitwise operators to OCaml's 'lsr' and 'asr'?

Tags: f#, ocaml, bitwise-operators

I have been looking at an OCaml implementation of [Hash Array Mapped Tries](https://github.com/thizanne/ocaml-hamt/blob/master/src/hamt.ml) and noticed that three distinct bit-level operators are used:

- `lsl`: left shift
- `lsr`: right shift
- `asr`: unsigned right shift

I would like to port this to F# but am unsure of the exact behavior of the F# bitwise operators.

The F# language reference gives two bitwise operators:

- `<<<`: left shift
- `>>>`: right shift

How would I use these operators to replicate the OCaml originals?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Well, it seems that you have provided the answer yourself, just use `>>>` and `<<<`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspecting the implementation of operator `<<<` and `>>>` hints at a solution (https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs)

```
let inline mask (n:int) (m:int) = (# "and" n m : int #)

[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
let inline (<<<) (x: ^T) (n:int) : ^T = 
     (^T: (static member (<<<) : ^T * int -> ^T) (x,n))
     when ^T : int32      = (# "shl" x (mask n 31) : int #)
     when ^T : uint32     = (# "shl" x (mask n 31) : uint32 #)
     when ^T : int64      = (# "shl" x (mask n 63) : int64 #)
     when ^T : uint64     = (# "shl" x (mask n 63) : uint64 #)
     when ^T : nativeint  = (# "shl" x n : nativeint #)
     when ^T : unativeint = (# "shl" x n : unativeint #)
     when ^T : int16      = (# "conv.i2" (# "shl" x (mask n 15) : int32  #) : int16 #)
     when ^T : uint16     = (# "conv.u2" (# "shl" x (mask n 15) : uint32 #) : uint16 #)
     when ^T : sbyte      = (# "conv.i1" (# "shl" x (mask n 7 ) : int32  #) : sbyte #)
     when ^T : byte       = (# "conv.u1" (# "shl" x (mask n 7 ) : uint32 #) : byte #)

[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
let inline (>>>) (x: ^T) (n:int) : ^T = 
     (^T: (static member (>>>) : ^T * int -> ^T) (x,n))
     when ^T : int32      = (# "shr"    x (mask n 31) : int32 #)
     when ^T : uint32     = (# "shr.un" x (mask n 31) : uint32 #)
     when ^T : int64      = (# "shr"    x (mask n 63) : int64 #)
     when ^T : uint64     = (# "shr.un" x (mask n 63) : uint64 #)
     when ^T : nativeint  = (# "shr"    x n : nativeint #)
     when ^T : unativeint = (# "shr.un" x n : unativeint #)
     when ^T : int16      = (# "conv.i2" (# "shr"    x (mask n 15) : int32  #) : int16 #)
     when ^T : uint16     = (# "conv.u2" (# "shr.un" x (mask n 15) : uint32 #) : uint16 #)
     when ^T : sbyte      = (# "conv.i1" (# "shr"    x (mask n 7 ) : int32  #) : sbyte #)
     when ^T : byte       = (# "conv.u1" (# "shr.un" x (mask n 7 ) : uint32 #) : byte #)
```

This code uses inline IL as well type-overloading only available to F# devs but the interesting rows seems to be:

```
when ^T : int32      = (# "shr"    x (mask n 31) : int32 #)
when ^T : uint32     = (# "shr.un" x (mask n 31) : uint32 #)
```

To shift right the `int32` version then uses `shr` (signed shift right) which corresponds to `asr`, the `uint32` uses `shr.un` (unsigned shift right) which corresponds to `lsr`.

The shift left versions all uses `shl`.

So for `int32` a potential solution could be:

```
module ShiftOps =
    let inline ( lsl ) (x: int32) (n:int) : int32 = x <<< n
    let inline ( lsr ) (x: int32) (n:int) : int32 = int32 (uint32 x >>> n)
    let inline ( asr ) (x: int32) (n:int) : int32 = x >>> n

open ShiftOps

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "0x%x" <| -1 lsr 4
    printfn "0x%x" <| -1 asr 4
    printfn "0x%x" <| -1 lsl 4

    0
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for digging into the source! Shouldn't `lsr` and `asr` be switched in your definition though?

Comment: I interpreted `asr` as arthimetic shift right which on my old 68000 meant shift right signed. That might not be how it works on OCAML

Answer (score 3):

In F# the kind of right shift is determined by the first operand. If it is unsigned, then the shift will be zero-padding, i.e., `asr`, otherwise it will be logical.

Comment: Thanks; so given I'm working with int32, and `of_uint32` and `to_int32` are defined as expected, I would have `let asr (x:int32) n = (to_int32 x) >>> n |> of_uint32`?

Comment: yes, looks correct to me. But I would rewrite it with: `let ast x n = uint32 (int32 x >>> n)`. (I always not sure about the precedence of logical operatos.